# Solve integral analytically

Tags: calculus, integration

Could this integral be solved analytically?

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}  \frac{(x+1)^2(x-1)\cos(x)}{x^3(x-2)} \ \mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: WA shows that the antiderivative uses the cosine and sine integrals.

Comment: you can solve, no where to start

Comment: The integral is infinite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concerning the antiderivative, it can be established using first partial fraction decomposition since $$\frac{(x+1)^2(x-1)}{x^3(x-2)}=\frac{1}{2 x^3}+\frac{3}{4 x^2}-\frac{1}{8 x}+\frac{9}{8 (x-2)}$$ and we already see that the result will make appearing sine and cosine integrals.

Multiplying each term by $\cos(x)$ and integrating we then have $$\int \frac{\cos(x)}{2 x^3}\,dx=-\frac{x^2 \text{Ci}(x)-x \sin (x)+\cos (x)}{4 x^2}$$ $$\int\frac{3\cos(x)}{4 x^2}\,dx=-\frac{3 (x \text{Si}(x)+\cos (x))}{4 x}$$ $$-\int\frac{\cos(x)}{8 x}\,dx=-\frac{\text{Ci}(x)}{8}$$ $$\int\frac{9\cos (x)}{8 (x-2)}\,dx=\frac{9}{8} (\cos (2) \text{Ci}(2-x)+\sin (2) \text{Si}(2-x))$$ which makes $$\int  \frac{(x+1)^2(x-1)\cos(x)}{x^3(x-2)} \, dx$$ perfectly explicit.

The real problem is the computation of the resulting expression at $x=0$; its value is $-\infty$. You could see it looking at the expansion of the result around $x=0$ $$-\frac{1}{4 x^2}-\frac{3}{4 x}-\frac{3}{8} (-3 \text{Ci}(2) \cos (2)-3 \text{Si}(2)
   \sin (2)+\log (x)+\gamma -1)-\frac{3}{16} x \left(2+3 \sin ^2(2)+3 \cos
   ^2(2)\right)+O\left(x^2\right)$$

The problem could have been detected from the integrand itself since, around $x=0$ $$ \frac{(x+1)^2(x-1)\cos(x)}{x^3(x-2)}=\frac{1}{2 x^3}+\frac{3}{4 x^2}-\frac{3}{8 x}-\frac{15}{16}-\frac{19
   x}{96}+O\left(x^2\right)$$

For $$\int_{a}^{b}  \frac{(x+1)^2(x-1)\cos(x)}{x^3(x-2)} \ \mathrm{d}x$$ provided $a>0$ and $b>0$, there would not be any problem.

Comment: thanks for your time enlighten me pretty

Comment: @susydiaz. You are very welcome, be sure ! Cheers :-)